# How do I know if an embedded systems project is using an embedded operating system?

Tags: c, operating-system, embedded

I followed [these instructions](https://openwsn.atlassian.net/wiki/display/OW/IAR) and was successfully transmitting [IEEE 802.15.4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.15.4) frames on a GINA Mote.  I know it was working because I have a packet sniffer that captured transmitted packets.

Here is the source code: https://github.com/openwsn-berkeley/openwsn-fw/tree/d1ec9982fbc101061b4bc70bde239e54cd1367c4/firmware/openos/bsp/boards/gina

I'm a little confused how and why it's working though.   Is this code loading an operating system (like RTOS) on the Gina mote or is this project OS-less ?

I'm looking for a solution that does not require an OS / bootloader.

I would appreciate if one of the experts in the community could weigh in on this.

Comment: ... don't you have the source code?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add link to source! I've edited the question above.

Comment: openwsn uses either a small kernel (just a small scheduler), or can use FreeRTOS. If you're using the first one, you're running the stack without any third party OS. The code you linked to is the bsp part of the code which compiles an image for the Gina board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JTAG adapter rams the executable image up the MSP430 processor's butt, sets up the MSP430 to start executing at the image's start address, and lets 'er rip.  That's it.  There ain't no OS, and there's no code onboard the little processor board required for loading the executable image.  Your program is the only code it ever knows.  (And the JTAG adapter probably burns the code into the processor's flash, so it stays resident even when the JTAG adapter is removed.... and starts executing again any time the processor is reset.)

Now, you may wonder... There may be C runtime facilities available that you might think are associated with an operating system... perhaps `printf()`, `malloc()`, `new`, etc.  Those are part of the C runtime & I/O subsystem, and can of course be implemented for a custom platform with no OS.

UPDATE:  Hmm.  What I mentioned above was true when I played around with small MSP430's back in 2008.  At that time I only recall IAR, I don't recall there being mspgcc.  I believe the IAR solution is as I described above.  The mspgcc solution seems to involve a "BSL" (bootstrap loader), per [this web page](https://openwsn.atlassian.net/wiki/display/OW/mspgcc).  Or perhaps the BSL is just pre-loaded on the MSP430, and even IAR uses it... I dunno.  In any case, with either the IAR or mspgcc toolchain, ultimately you should be able to burn your program into the processor's built-in flash, and once burnt into it, you can remove your JTAG programming/debugging adapter, and from then on, the CPU will automatically run your program every time it boots.

Comment: thanks for this response.  So it appears like both you and PurpleAlien agree that the GINA project is OS-less (i.e. a kernel is not needed and just burns an image to the MSP430).